# Use wget to download an incomplete link

Tags: python, wget

I am quite new to using wget.
I am using python to write a script to download many files.
Files are following a pattern with date so I can simply go:

```
for date in daterange:
    link = "my_string%s"%date
    wget(link, output)
```

The problem is in all the files there is a portion of the string I can't know in advance. They are a couple of random numbers (time of processing)

The question is, is there a way to download a link while only knowing the whole string partially.
Can you request the whole string or something?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be disappointingly short:

> The question is, is there a way to download a link while only knowing the whole string partially. Can you request the whole string or something?

No.  (a lot of security actually relies on that being impossible!)

(also, when using python, you'd typically not use the external wget program, but just use a python library for doing downloads, like `requests`)