# How to download a folder from a webserver which the developer left accidently, while the directory listing is disabled?

Tags: wget, download, web

There is a backup folder at the location `https://abc.efg.com/assets/images/socialIcons%20(copy)/`, which the developer left by mistake, and I want to download it, as a part of vulnerability assessment (which I am just learning by doing).

Directory Listing is NOT enabled on the website.

So how do I download this particular folder?

***What I Tried:***

```
wget -r --no-parent "abc.efg.com/assets/images/socialIcons (copy)/"                                                                              4 ⨯

--2021-12-02 01:26:16--  http://abc.efg.com/assets/images/socialIcons%20(copy)/
Resolving abc.efg.com (abc.efg.com)... 103.8.14.34
Connecting to abc.efg.com (abc.efg.com)|103.8.14.34|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2021-12-02 01:28:25--  (try: 2)  http://abc.efg.com/assets/images/socialIcons%20(copy)/
Connecting to abc.efg.com (abc.efg.com)|103.8.14.34|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2021-12-02 01:30:32--  (try: 3)  http://abc.efg.com/assets/images/socialIcons%20(copy)/
Connecting to abc.efg.com (abc.efg.com)|103.8.14.34|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use wget to download an incomplete link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673278/use-wget-to-download-an-incomplete-link)

Comment: short answer: you can't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No. That's about downloading files where they know only partial names. I need to download a folder and i know its complete path

Comment: it's exactly the point: you can only download *files* with a full path, not a "directory".